# How can I turn off color in ipdb?

Tags: ipdb

When I embed the code ina python script

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

the colors clash with default Xterm color scheme

Answer (score 2):

Old answer - insert this into code (2019, doesn't work):

```
import ipdb; ipdb.def_colors='NoColor'; ipdb.set_trace()
```

Updated answer based on [latest IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html)

1 - run at prompt to create default profile:

```
ipython profile create
```

2 - edit /your home dir/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py

Add at top

```
c = get_config()
```

Then add

```
c.InteractiveShell.colors = 'NoColor'
```

Comment: @user3673, I've updated answer to reflect ipython changes